# Accessing main arguments outside of main on Linux

Tags: c, linux, elf

Is it possible to access the arguments to `main` outside of `main` (namely in a shared library constructor) on Linux other than by parsing `/proc/self/cmdline`?

Comment: C does not define any way to access the command-line arguments other than via the parameters of the `main()` function.  That function can pass those parameters to other functions, but no other function can obtain them autonomously (via any facility defined by the language).

Comment: The question this was marked as a duplicate of is how to pass the arguments of `main()` to another function.  This question asks how to access the command-line arguments of a process *before `main()` is even called*.  That's completely different.  There's probably a dupe out there, but the one selected isn't it.

Comment: Previous duplicate was [Process argc and argv outside of main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862798/process-argc-and-argv-outside-of-main).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by putting the constructor in the `.init_array` section. Functions in the `.init_array` (unlike `.init`) are called with the same arguments `main` will be called with: `argc`, `argv` and `env`.

Here's a simple example. I used `LD_PRELOAD` simply to avoid complicating the example with code which actually links and uses a shared library, but it would work in a more normal scenario as well.

#### file: printargs.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int printargs(int argc, char** argv, char** env) {
  puts("In printargs:");
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  printf("  Arg %d (%p) '%s'\n", i, (void*)argv[i], argv[i]);
  return 0;
}

/* Put the function into the init_array */
__attribute__((section(".init_array"))) static void *ctr = &printargs;
```

#### Build and use the shared library

(If you use `-Wall`, you will see a warning, because `ctr` is unused.)

```
$ gcc -o printargs.so -std=c11 -shared -fpic printargs.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=./printargs.so /bin/echo Hello, world.
In printargs:
  Arg 0 (0x7ffc7617102f) '/bin/echo'
  Arg 1 (0x7ffc76171039) 'Hello,'
  Arg 2 (0x7ffc76171040) 'world.'
Hello, world.
```

This solution comes from a suggestion by [Mike Frysinger in the libc-help mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-11/msg00006.html) and there is an even more laconic version of this answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34916546/1566221).

Comment: I misread the question. Thanks for the feedback with my answer. :-)

Comment: Note that if the application modifies `argv[n]` before the library is loaded, you will get modified command line this way, while you would get original command line from `/proc/self/cmdline`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: That depends on what you mean by "modifies argv[n]". If the application changes the value of argv[n], then that will not be reflected in /proc/self/cmdline. If it changes the string that argv[n] points at (say, changing its case), then the change will be visible in /proc/self/cmdline. In the vast majority of cases, though, no changes are made and if you really wanted to ensure that you saw the original values, you should either use a wrapper around main or LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @emloyed: also, as I was just reminded, `/proc/self/cmdline`  is truncated at 4096 bytes, so it might only give you part of the arguments.

Comment: When using compiler/linker optimizations, the compiler/linker may remove the `ctr` variable and the `.init_array` section. You can add `__attribute__((used))` to the definition of `ctr` to avoid this.